# mySQL multiple Table select over 3 tables

Tags: mysql

how would I write a single SQL statement to extract TEMPLATE_NAME (TEMPLATES) and all AREA_NAMEs (TEMPLATE_AREAS) given a PAGE_ID from the following tables:

[image]

Sorry if this is stupidly easy. Im quite new at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.TEMPLATE_NAME, a.AREA_NAME
from page_versions p
inner join templates t on t.template_id = p.template_id
inner join template_areas a on a.template_id = t.template_id
where p.page_id = 123
```

Comment: is t a and p the table names?

Comment: it is an alias for the table name. That way you can save the typing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.TEMPLATE_NAME, A.AREA_NAME
FROM PAGE_VERSIONS P
LEFT JOIN TEMPLATES T ON T.TEMPLATE_ID = P.TEMPLATE_ID
LEFT JOIN TEMPLATE_AREAS A ON A.TEMPLATE_ID = P.TEMPLATE_ID
WHERE P.PAGE_ID = yourPageId;
```

Comment: is t a and p the table names?

Comment: respective table alias. you can change it if you want.